# Poisson Distribution homework

Tags: poisson-distribution

I need some help in the next example, as it could be in the exam next week.

Description:
We are collecting seashells at the beach, and we find that out of 300 seashells 4 are nautilus. What's the probability that from the next 100 seashells we pick up 2 are nautilus?

Okay, so lambda is 4/300, but I'm not sure how to deal with the 100 situation.
100 is 1/3 of 300 so do I just divide lambda by 1/3 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem about Poisson distribution.

We are asking about how many event of success out of $100$ trials.

This is a Binomial distribution where $n=100$ and $p = \frac{4}{300}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then my proff might placed this and another similar exercise under the wrong category.